# replace a textnode that has non-textnode siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

For this HTML

> <label
>   id="nameWrapper"><input
>   type="checkbox" name="name"
>   />guest</label>

What's the shortest javascript code to replace `guest` with other text? What I can think of is,

```
$('#nameWrapper').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).replaceWith('other text');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-jQuery method.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/NLJ3e/

```
document.getElementById('nameWrapper').lastChild.data = 'new text';
```

Or shorten it with a jQuery selector:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/NLJ3e/1/

```
$('#nameWrapper')[0].lastChild.data = 'new text';
```

Or a little longer (and slower), but more jQuery-like:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/NLJ3e/2/

```
$('#nameWrapper').contents().last().replaceWith('new text');
```